# How to scrollup page after click on mat-paginator?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I need to scroll up page after clicking on [mat-paginator](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview) component. I use custom service for this purpose before, like this:

```
function _window(): any {
  return window;
}

export class WindowService {
  get nativeWindow(): any {
    return _window();
  }
}
```

and use it on component

```
constructor(private winRef: WindowService) {}
...
this.winRef.nativeWindow.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

But somehow this doesn't work when I start use material component. 
So, on my current html I have the next code:

```
<mat-paginator [length]="totalCount"
                 pageSize="10"
                 (page)="pageEvent = $event"
                 (click)="onPaginator()">
  </mat-paginator>
```

And on .ts have the next function:

```
 onPaginator() {
    this.winRef.nativeWindow.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
```

But page don't scroll up.
So, how it's possible to achieve scrolling up page after clicking on paginator?

Comment: Have you tried `document.querySelector('#ComponentIdWhereYouWantToScrollTo')
    .scrollIntoView()` ?

Comment: You're right! The answer was much easier than I thought.